# How to wrap text on a jQM image button?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am trying to wrap text on a image button:

[image]

I get New Document, but I want to be

New

Document

```
#menuoptions .ui-block-a.ui-btn.ui-btn-inline.ui-btn-corner-all.ui-shadow.ui-btn-up-c {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}

#imglogo {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="newdocument.html" rel="external" class="ui-block-a ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">
            <img src="img/calendar.png" id="imglogo" width="75" height="75">New Document</span></span></a>
```

Comment: Hi Marcus, yeah that does not solve it, and I don't want to add br to my text, it's already super messy. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.ui-btn-text {width: 75px; display: block;}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Ls9dN/1/)

Comment: It this does'nt work, and neither does inserting a break, like `New<br />Document`, your not changing the actual code that is ouputted on your screen, or some javascript is overriding it. Try setting the css to !important, and use the console in your browser to see where the overriding styles are coming from.

Comment: br works but right aligns the text, and i don't want to have br on the tags.